# Failed to build gem native extension (installing ruby-debug-ide-0.7.1.beta3.gem)

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, jruby

I'm using

- IntelliJ 2019.3.4 build #IU-193.6911.18
- Jruby 9.2.11.0
- Ruby 2.6.5 + DevKit

When I want to debug, I get a message from RubyMine debugger:

> debugging gems are not installed. Would you like to install them?

When installing I get following message:

```
Following gems were not installed: 
C:\Users\stomph\.IntelliJIdea2019.3\config\plugins\ruby\rb\gems\ruby-debug-ide-0.7.1.beta3.gem: Error installing ruby-debug-ide-0.7.1.beta3.gem: 
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. 
current directory: C:/jruby-9.2.11.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.1.beta3/ext C:/jruby-9.2.11.0/bin/jruby.exe mkrf_conf.rb current directory: 
C:/jruby-9.2.11.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.1.beta3/ext 

C:jruby-9.2.11.0binjruby.exe -S rake 
RUBYARCHDIR\=C:/jruby-9.2.11.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/extensions/universal-java-1.8/2.5.0/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.1.beta3 
RUBYLIBDIR\=C:/jruby-9.2.11.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/extensions/universal-java-1.8/2.5.0/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.1.beta3 

rake failed
Cannot run program "C:jruby-9.2.11.0binjruby.exe" (in directory "C:\jruby-9.2.11.0\lib\ruby\gems\shared\gems\ruby-debug-ide-0.7.1.beta3\ext"): CreateProcess error=2, 
The system cannot find the file specified 
Gem files will remain installed in C:/jruby-9.2.11.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.1.beta3 for inspection. 
Results logged to C:/jruby-9.2.11.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/extensions/universal-java-1.8/2.5.0/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.1.beta3/gem_make.out  
Native compilation failed. Please make sure that you have Ruby DevKit installed"
```

Ruby DevKit and rake are installed so I'm not getting what's wrong

The content of `gem_make.out` is:

```
current directory: C:/jruby-9.2.11.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.1.beta3/ext
C:/jruby-9.2.11.0/bin/jruby.exe mkrf_conf.rb

current directory: C:/jruby-9.2.11.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.1.beta3/ext
C:jruby-9.2.11.0binjruby.exe -S rake RUBYARCHDIR\=C:/jruby-9.2.11.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/extensions/universal-java-1.8/2.5.0/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.1.beta3 RUBYLIBDIR\=C:/jruby-9.2.11.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/extensions/universal-java-1.8/2.5.0/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.1.beta3
rake failed
Cannot run program "C:jruby-9.2.11.0binjruby.exe" (in directory "C:\jruby-9.2.11.0\lib\ruby\gems\shared\gems\ruby-debug-ide-0.7.1.beta3\ext"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: Hello Harry, and welcome to SO. You question is hard to read: please spend a few minutes to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60862715/edit) it and format it properly.

Comment: Would it be possible to share also the content of C:/jruby-9.2.11.0/lib/ruby/gems/shared/extensions/universal-java-1.8/2.5.0/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.1.beta3/gem_make.out?

Comment: content of gem_make.out added

Answer (score 3):

After trying a lot the following solved the problem:

> gem install ruby-debug-ide

Then ruby-debug-ide-0.7.0.gem is installed and everything is working!